# Table of Contents -display picture

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to have a table of contents that shows the title of the chapter in the list with a picture display. how to do it?
As in the figure below[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: etoc package might be good

Comment: I have no command yet
In fact, I just had an idea and didn't start
I guess maybe someone has already done this to help me . ... Its design rseems to be a problem really